# ASIHTTPRequestErrorDomain Code=4 "The request was cancelled"

Tags: asihttprequest

I got "Error Domain=ASIHTTPRequestErrorDomain Code=4 \"The request was cancelled\" exception. but I do not cancel the request.

How could it be?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

By default, if a request running in a queue fails, all other requests in the queue will be cancelled.

You can disable this with:

```
[queue setShouldCancelAllRequestsOnFailure:NO];
```

Comment: But I don't use any queue requests. Just single synchronous request starts every second.

Comment: Add some code to your question then, and switch on the debug logging in asihttprequest, and add that to your question too.